# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, carousel

I am trying to build a carousel of 3 svg icons. I took the raw HTML from Bootstrap. However, it isn't sliding. It is only showing the first icon and there are no arrows to slide. As i am still a HTML beginner I would really like someone to explain the problem, I can't figure it out.
Here is my piece of HTML code:

````
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="assets/images/EDARA.svg" style ="height: 200px;" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h4 style="color: grey">e-DARA</h4>
                      <p style="color: grey;">A fully fledged government solution </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="assets/images/MIGRATIONKIT.svg" style = "height: 200px;" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h4 style = "color: grey">Migration Kit</h4>
                      <p>A tool allowing email migration from any source to a Private or Public Cloud </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                      <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                      <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

did you import the javascript for bootstrap?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div
      id="carouselExampleIndicators"
      class="carousel slide container"
      data-bs-ride="true"
    >
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide-to="0"
          class="active"
          aria-current="true"
          aria-label="Slide 1"
        ></button>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide-to="1"
          aria-label="Slide 2"
        ></button>
        <button
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide-to="2"
          aria-label="Slide 3"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img
            src="assets/images/image.png"
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="assets/images/image.png"
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img
            src="assets/images/image.png"
            class="d-block w-100"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        class="carousel-control-prev"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        data-bs-slide="prev"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button
        class="carousel-control-next"
        type="button"
        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        data-bs-slide="next"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note the `<link>` and `<script>` tags